# how to fetch distinct objects in array : Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, distinct

I am trying to fetch unique objects from an array which may have duplicate objects. I have tried new Set and new Map but i still haven't gotten my result.

For example i have the following array of objects

```
const myArray = [{ x: 10, y: 22}, {  x: 11,  y: 22}, {  x: 12,  y: 22}, {  x: 12,  y: 22}, {  x: 12,  y: 23}];

console.log([...new Set(myArray.map((item) => item.x && item.y ))]) // [22, 23]
```

when i want this

```
[{ x: 10, y: 22}, {  x: 11,  y: 22}, {  x: 12,  y: 22}, {  x: 12,  y: 23}];
```

it should remove the fourth object in myArray, since it is repeating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce for that along with some:

```js
const myArray = [{ x: 10, y: 22}, {  x: 11,  y: 22}, {  x: 12,  y: 22}, {  x: 12,  y: 22}, {  x: 12,  y: 23}];

const Filtered = [];

const filterDuplicates = myArray.reduce((arr, el) => {
    if(!arr.some(current => current.x === el.x && current.y === el.y)) {
       arr.push(el);
    }
    return arr;
}, Filtered);

console.log(Filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

What your `map` returns as follows

```
myArray.map((item) => item.x && item.y)   // [ 22, 22, 22, 22, 23 ]
```

because it first check wheather the `item.x` is `truthy` or not. As it `true` always so it returns the `value` after `&&`

and when you apply the `set`, It will filter the unique value from the array

```
[...new Set(myArray.map((item) => item.x && item.y))]    // [ 22, 23 ]
```

**Alternate apprach**

```js
const myArray = [
  { x: 10, y: 22 },
  { x: 11, y: 22 },
  { x: 12, y: 22 },
  { x: 12, y: 22 },
  { x: 12, y: 23 },
];

const strArray = myArray.map(({ x, y }) => `${x}/${y}`);
const str = [...new Set(strArray)];
const result = str.map((str) => {
  const [x, y] = str.split("/");
  return { x, y };
});

console.log(result);
```